# What default fonts are used?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, default

I was wondering what fonts are used in Ubuntu 11.10 and are they open source? The fonts used in Ubuntu have very cute Armenian character support, that's why I would like to know them, so I can install them on my Symbian smartphone whose fonts do not have Armenian character supprt.

EDIT: I would love to get additional information. In Firefox web browser the Armenian characters are displayed properly, and I would to know exactly which one of the fonts is the one used in Firefox as there are a lot of fonts in the downloaded archive. –

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the Ubuntu font family for its default fonts. The Ubuntu font is used for the desktop, while the terminal uses Ubuntu Mono.

You can see more about the fonts and download them [here](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

The Ubuntu fonts are distributed under the [Ubuntu Font license](http://font.ubuntu.com/ufl/), which is indeed open source.

Comment: @shahe Tajiryan, you are right. This is a perfect answer. I can upvote it. You can mark it as correct. Please do so. Then your question will not be one of the many unanswered questions on this site.

Comment: @ShaheTajiryan I'm not completely sure, but I'd say it might be `Ubuntu-R.ttf`, since that's the Ubuntu Regular font. Someone else could correct me in another comment if I'm wrong. You may have to experiment until it looks right.

Comment: Hmm, it's strange, because even with that font the Armenian chracters are not displayed. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find them on [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=ubuntu&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y) and [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu) ([Condensed](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu+Condensed) and [Mono](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu+Mono)) to embed them via CSS in websites.