# What default fonts are used in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

What are the default fonts used in Kubuntu, and what are their sizes?

I am asking about the default general font, terminal font, etc.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/69827/what-default-fonts-are-used because that question was about Ubuntu Unity.

Comment: Why not look yourself (boot up the release you want in a VM and look). It's likely those details differ as KDE changes versions, so unless you look up the details via the package as regards changes, why not boot the version that interests you and look.

Comment: You can easily [research](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) this on your own by firing up a live session of [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org) ;)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi KDE Plasma uses Noto Sans, I'm pretty sure. You can check this by going to Settings > Fonts > General

Comment: Finally, downloaded and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General**: Noto Sans 10pt

**Fixed width**: Hack 9pt

**Small**: Noto Sans 8pt

**Toolbar,Menu,Window title**: Noto Sans 10pt